# Writing game engine using SDL2 and C++, my sprite and collision box separate when moving at angle

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics, sdl-2

Basically I'm trying to implement a game engine using C++ and SDL2, and for the most part things are going smooth.

Collision detection works (using Separation Axis Theorem), movement, etc. but when I'm drawing the vertices of my collision box, and my sprite moves at an angle, the sprite and collision box move away from each other.

I'm not sure what's going on, I have two different angles to represent the angle of the image itself and the movement angle, and I've tried adjusting them with constants, adjusting which one changes and how with the movement, etc, but they still don't move together (when moving at an angle).

It's not a drawing error as the when the collision box hits another sprite's collision box, it detects that collision.

I'll leave code I think is relevant below, but I think it's a lot so I'll also leave a link to the repo if someone would rather look at that. [Repo link](https://github.com/fonkvan/DLAY_Fall2021_GameEngine).

Relevant classes are probably Sprite and Ship, relevant functions: Sprite::VectorProjection, Sprite::UpdateVertices, Sprite::MoveSprite, Ship::PlayerInput

Code:

```
//Sprite.cpp

void Sprite::VectorProjection(double Speed)
{
    Velocity.x = Speed * cos(MoveAngle) + Acceleration.x;
    Velocity.y = Speed * sin(MoveAngle) + Acceleration.y;
    this->Speed = sqrt((Velocity.x * Velocity.x) + (Velocity.y * Velocity.y));
    MoveAngle = atan2(Velocity.y, Velocity.x);
}

void Sprite::UpdateVertices()
{
    std::vector<Vec2D> NewVerts;
    Vec2D vert;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); ++i)
    {
        vert.x = ((vertices[i].x - Center.x) * cos(ImageAngle - LastAngle)) - ((vertices[i].y - Center.y) * sin(ImageAngle - LastAngle)) + Center.x;
        vert.y = ((vertices[i].x - Center.x)*sin(ImageAngle - LastAngle)) + ((vertices[i].y - Center.y)*cos(ImageAngle - LastAngle)) + Center.y;
        NewVerts.push_back(vert);
    }
    LastAngle = ImageAngle;
    vertices = NewVerts;
}

void Sprite::MoveSprite()
{
    std::vector<Vec2D> NewVerts;
    Vec2D vert;
    texture.x += Velocity.x;
    texture.y += Velocity.y;
    Position.x += Velocity.x;
    Position.y += Velocity.y;
    Center.x += Velocity.x;
    Center.y += Velocity.y;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); ++i)
    {
        vert.x = vertices[i].x + Velocity.x;
        vert.y = vertices[i].y + Velocity.y;
        NewVerts.push_back(vert);
    }
    vertices = NewVerts;
}

--------------------------------------------------
//Ship.cpp

void Ship::PlayerInput(SDL_Event Event, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    double IA;
    double MA;
    if(Event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        if (Event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
        {
            Fire();
        }
    }
    if (Event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if (Event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w)
        {
            //MoveAngle = -M_PI/2;
            SetSpeed(2.00);
            MoveSprite();
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        if (Event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_a)
        {
            IA = ConvertToDegrees(ImageAngle);
            MA = ConvertToDegrees(MoveAngle);
            SetImageAngle(IA - 1);
            SetMoveAngle(MA - 1);
            UpdateVertices();
        }
        if (Event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_d)
        {
            IA = ConvertToDegrees(ImageAngle);
            MA = ConvertToDegrees(MoveAngle);
            SetImageAngle(IA + 1);
            SetMoveAngle(MA + 1);
            UpdateVertices();
        }
    }
    if (Event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
    {
        SetSpeed(0.00);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Image of what's happening: [The blue dots are the vertices and the image of the sprite should be *inside* of it. When moving left/right, up/down, it stays inside, but at an angle this happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYA0h.png)

EDIT: was asked for code where I calculate vertices, and render them, here's that:

```
//Initial set of vertices:
void Sprite::SetVertices()
{
    Vec2D vert1{(double)texture.x, (double)texture.y};
    Vec2D vert2{(double)texture.x + (double)texture.w, (double)texture.y};
    Vec2D vert3{(double)texture.x, (double)texture.y + (double)texture.h};
    Vec2D vert4{(double)texture.x + (double)texture.w, (double)texture.y + (double)texture.h};
    //Order of insertion of vertices matters
    vertices.push_back(vert1);
    vertices.push_back(vert3);
    vertices.push_back(vert4);
    vertices.push_back(vert2);
}

-------------------------------------------
//Vertices are drawn in the Tick function of the Scene class
void Scene::Tick()
{
    bool bWindowVisible = true;
    SDL_Event Event;
    while (bPlay)
    {
        CurrentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        DeltaTime = CurrentTime - LastTime;
        if (DeltaTime.count() < RefreshSeconds)
        {
            continue; //only used here to clean up code and help alleviate several layers of nesting
        }
        LastTime = CurrentTime;
        if (!bPaused)
        {
            SDL_PollEvent(&Event);
            EventHandler(Event, OUT bPlay, OUT bPaused);
            SDL_RenderClear(Renderer);
            for (Sprite* s : Sprites)
            {
                s->Update(Renderer);
                SDL_RenderCopyEx(Renderer, s->Image, NULL, &s->texture, s->ConvertToDegrees(s->ImageAngle), NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);

                //Draws vertices for debugging
                for (Vec2D vert : s->vertices)
                {
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Renderer, 0, 0, 255, 255);
                    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(Renderer, vert.x, vert.y);
                }
            }
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
            SDL_RenderPresent(Renderer);
        }
        else
        {
            PausedEventHandler(OUT bPlay, OUT bPaused); // this function was also created to help alleviate 
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I have problems understanding your code, especially which part represents the sprite and which one the collision box.

Comment: That being said, you may be approaching this the wrong way. When representing an object you normally have its vertices that represent its shape and vertices representing the collision box. These coordinates are in the model space which makes it easy to ensure that they match. In addition to that, you have transformations that you use to place it correctly in the scene. The same transformation is used for the sprite and its collision box. And you only update these transformations, based on the input.

Comment: @t.niese there is no explicit collision box, in a sense, the 'collision box' is calculated from the sprite (it's honestly not even a box, it is simply the vertices due to the way the Separation Axis Theorem works, there's no need for an actual box). So like, the only thing here representing the 'collision box' is the array vertices, texture is a SDL_Rect that is important to the image of the sprite itself, center is the center of the sprite, and position is the upper left corner of the sprite (simply because that's how SDL uses images)

Comment: Ok but if you get the collision box from the vertices of the sprite and use those for rendering the blue dots, then the part where you do the rendering would be important, and that one is missing?

Comment: @t.niese now included

Comment: @t.niese hey I found a solution myself, I'm going to post it in the original post in case anyone in the future needs help.

Comment: @fonkvan if you have the solution, please post it as an answer to your own question and accept the answer; that's how we do it here, it's not standard practice here to edit your own post with the solution without posting an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @RandomDavis ah sorry, first time I've posted here before. I posted the solution as an actual answer now. Thanks for helping with the proper etiquette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an image in SDL is defined by it's point in the upperleft corner, it does not rotate with the image (so if you rotate the image, the point remains the same). However when moving at an angle, all the other points in the image will move relative to that angle, but not that point, which would cause a separation of the collision box and the sprite itself. The issue was in this code block

```
void Sprite::MoveSprite()
{
    std::vector<Vec2D> NewVerts;
    Vec2D vert;
    texture.x += Velocity.x;
    texture.y += Velocity.y;
    Position.x += Velocity.x;
    Position.y += Velocity.y;
    Center.x += Velocity.x;
    Center.y += Velocity.y;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); ++i)
    {
        vert.x = vertices[i].x + Velocity.x;
        vert.y = vertices[i].y + Velocity.y;
        NewVerts.push_back(vert);
    }
    vertices = NewVerts;
}
```

Where I assumed the texture coordinates should move with the velocity. To fix this, I created a variable called D and defined it as the distance between the texture coordinate and the center

```
D.x = Center.x - texture.x;
D.y = Center.y - texture.y;
```

This will work since the texture coordinate is always in the upperleft corner
then we change the movesprite method to say this:

```
void Sprite::MoveSprite()
{
    std::vector<Vec2D> NewVerts;
    Vec2D vert;
    Position.x += Velocity.x;
    Position.y += Velocity.y;
    Center.x += Velocity.x;
    Center.y += Velocity.y;
    texture.x = Center.x - D.x;
    texture.y = Center.y - D.y;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); ++i)
    {
        vert.x = vertices[i].x + Velocity.x;
        vert.y = vertices[i].y + Velocity.y;
        NewVerts.push_back(vert);
    }
    vertices = NewVerts;
}
```

and problem is resolved!

Comment: Great that you figured that out yourself. I suspected something like this when I read the SDL documentation, but I couldn't pinpoint the exact location in your code that is a problem.

Comment: @t.niese yeah, and that makes sense, there's a lot of moving parts and I can see it being difficult debugging when you can't see the whole picture (or the whole picture is several hundred lines of code across multiple classes)